# Collecting Microsoft Windows DHCP Server Operational Event Logs

Tags: splunk

We would like to collect Microsoft Windows DHCP Server Operational Event Logs into Splunk and seem to be having some trouble.

The path to the logs that we're interested in within the windows Event Viewer navigational tree is

```
> Applications and Services Logs
 > Microsoft
  > Windows
   > DHCP-Server
    -  Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Server Events/Operational
```

We believe that the problem is with our input configuration and we've tried a number of different configurations in inputs.conf which seem appropriate for this app including the following but we're yet to receive any events.

```
[WinEventLog://Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Server Events/Operational]
```

and

```
[WinEventLog://Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server/Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Server Events/Operational]
```

These configurations have resulted in the following errors:

> message from ""C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\bin\splunk-winevtlog.exe"" splunk-winevtlog - WinEventMon::configure: Failed to find Event Log with channel name='Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Server Events/Operational'
>
> message from ""C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\bin\splunk-winevtlog.exe"" splunk-winevtlog - WinEventMon::configure: Failed to find Event Log with channel name='Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server/Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Server Events/Operational'

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the correct **Full Name** is to *right click on the log leaf node* and select *Properties* and on the *General Tab* you will see a ***Full Name*** field. Select the full contents of the field and paste that exact value into your inputs.conf e.g [WinEventLog://Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client/Operational] name.

I don't have a DHCP Server to copy the exact value but I am pretty sure it will be something like "Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Server/Operational".

Answer (score 0):

> [WinEventLog://DhcpAdminEvents]

That works, it's probably Microsoft's problem with sticking to common naming